# In XSLT, how do I truncate a value to the first five characters?

Tags: xml, xslt

So, I know absolutely nothing about XSLT.  I don't know what I'm doing, I don't know what I'm supposed to make the code do, and I don't know how to make it do whatever it is supposed to do.

That being said, I know I'm supposed to truncate a name to the first five characters.

I have this:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(/myQuery/Arguments/FirstName) &gt;= 6">
<xsl:variable name = "x" select = "substring(/myQuery/Arguments/FirstName, 1, 5)"/>
</xsl:if>
```

So, that *does* assign a truncated version of FirstName to X.  But how do I get it back into FirstName?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Copy your input and just truncate this name ? This is code output nothing. If you want for exemple output something <FirstName>valueOfX</FirstName> just add <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="$x"/></FirstName>

Comment: I'm not sure what I want to achieve.  I'm new on the job, and have no idea what the code is supposed to do, let alone the fact that I don't know this programming language.

I just know that there is a GUI with some text fields.  One of them is the name.  I'm supposed to send just the first five characters of the name.  I don't know where or how it's being sent, but I need to make it just five characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us much to work with, but let's begin with this: an XSLT processor doesn't modify anything.  Rather it takes an XML input and *produces* a transformed version (which is not necessarily XML).

Reverse-engineering your XSL leads me to believe that your input document could look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myQuery>
  <Arguments>
    <FirstName>Jonathon</FirstName>
  </Arguments>
</myQuery>
```

If the objective is to produce a document that is the same, except for truncating the text in the `<FirstName>` element, then that might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- by default, transform every node and attribute into a copy of itself -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Where needed, transform FirstName elements with truncation -->
  <xsl:template match="/myQuery/Arguments/FirstName[string-length(.) &gt; 5]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 5)" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transforming the example input above via that stylesheet yields

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myQuery>
<Arguments>
<FirstName>Jonat</FirstName>
</Arguments>
</myQuery>
```

Points to note:

- `<xsl:template>` elements define how different parts of the input document are transformed.  Document parts are selected via XPath expressions; the transformation is expressed by the body of the template.
- Where you want to produce a transformed document that has only small differences from the original, it greatly simplifies things to use an identity transform, such as the one appearing first in the above stylesheet.
- At most one template will selected for transforming any given node in the input document.  When more than one matches a given node, there are priority rules for choosing which one is used.  Pretty much anything has priority over the selector in the given identity transform, and where the priority is the same, the template appearing last in the stylesheet is chosen.

There's much more to XSLT, but I hope that gets you going.

Comment: So, if my three lines of code from above are inside their own <xsl:template name="Arguments">, then I assume that these <xsl:template match....> would NOT also go inside?  They'd be separete templates, right?

Comment: Correct, `<xsl:template>` elements do not nest.  Note, however, that your three lines do not transform anything.  They conditionally compute the truncated substring, but they don't do anything with it.  Both of the answers so far provided contain stylesheets that perform the full transformation.  (Answer edited to present the output.)

Comment: Hey, it worked!  Thanks! Is there an easy way to have it do the truncating for multiple variables, without having to make a separate <xsl:template match....> for each of them?

Comment: If you want to truncate all child elements of each `<Arguments>` element to at most five characters, then changing the one occurence of "FirstName" in the stylesheet to "node()" should yield a stylesheet that has that effect.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and then override what you're trying to change...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FirstName[string-length(normalize-space())>=6]/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(),1,5)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```